# wget unable to download anything from https sources.

Tags: homebrew

Using wget to download files from an https source is causing a `host is down` error.

```
$ wget https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
--2018-07-16 20:56:17--  https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
Resolving www.google.co.uk (www.google.co.uk)... 216.58.198.163
Connecting to www.google.co.uk (www.google.co.uk)|216.58.198.163|:443... failed: Host is down.
Retrying.

--2018-07-16 20:56:18--  (try: 2)  https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
Connecting to www.google.co.uk (www.google.co.uk)|216.58.198.163|:443... failed: Host is down.
Retrying.
```

When downloading files via http wget works as expected. I'm also able to download the file via `curl`. However, I prefer `wget`. As I'm using `wget -i` flag to download about 50 different files from a url.txt file.

I've tried downloading the source file via desktop Chrome, and again there's no issue.

`wget` is version `GNU Wget 1.19.5 built on darwin17.5.0.` and installed via `$ brew --version Homebrew 1.6.17 Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision f0ff; last commit 2018-07-15)`. I'd previously run into an issue with `pip` and `openssl` a while back. Which I've still been unable to fix. So wonder if this might becausing the issue?

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that your issues with `openssl` are indeed the cause. From the `wget` manpage:

> **HTTPS (SSL/TLS) Options**
>
> To support encrypted HTTP (HTTPS) downloads,
> Wget must be compiled with an external SSL library. The current
> default is GnuTLS.  In addition, Wget also supports HSTS (HTTP Strict
> TransportSecurity).  If Wget is compiled without SSL support, none of
> these options are available.

Comment: Openssl is installed and showing as `openssl version
LibreSSL 2.7.4`, I've even tried `brew install wget --with-libressl` but still no such luck. It's a real headscratcher that I can't seem to find what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

wget requires openssl

so make sure you have openssl installed on your homebrew system

```
$ brew list | grep ssl
openssl
openssl@1.1
```

If openssl is not installed then install it using "brew install openssl"

Comment: Openssl is installed. Which makes it all the more tricky to debug what's going wrong.
`brew list | grep ssl
libressl
openssl`